# Show by definition that $M=\{(x,y,z)|36x^2+4y^2-9z^2=36\}$ is a surface in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

Show by definition that $M=\{(x,y,z)|36x^2+4y^2-9z^2=36\}$ is a surface in $\Bbb R^3$.

**Definition**

A surface in $\Bbb R^3$ is a subset $M$ of $R^3$ such that for each point $p$ of $M$ there exists a proper patch (a 1-1 regular mapping of an open set $D$ of $\Bbb R^2$ into $\Bbb R^3$ for which the inverse function is continuous) in $M$ whose image contains a neighborhood of $p$ in $M$.

I came up with the patch $x(u,v)=(\operatorname{cosh}u\operatorname{cos}v,3\operatorname{cosh}u\operatorname{sin}v,2\operatorname{sinh}u)$ on $\Bbb R^2$. Then this is a regular mapping, however, it is not 1-1,and if I try to make it 1-1 by restricting the domain that it does not cover the whole surface, nor can I prove that the inverse is continuous.

How can I prove that $M$ is a surface directly from definition by finding proper patches in this case? I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Comment: Your description of the patch is incomplete, without saying what the domain and range are. Most likely, if you specified the domain carefully, it would be one-to-one and you could prove that the inverse is continuous. You also seem concerned about that one patch not covering the whole surface. Notice that the definition does not require that *one* patch cover the surface; it requires that some *set of patches* altogether cover the surface.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes you were right. But how can I show that the inverse map is continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patch you found is good. Let's write everything neatly. We have:

$${\bf x} \colon \Bbb R \times \left]0,2\pi\right[ \to M \\ {\bf x}(u,v) = (\cosh u \cos v, 3\cosh u \sin v, 2\sinh u)$$

This won't cover the whole surface: one meridian will be left out: the curve $(\cosh u,0,2\sinh u)$, which would correspond to ${\bf x}(u,0)$, but our domains must be open sets. You can take $\epsilon > 0$ and use the same expression to define a patch with domain $\Bbb R \times \left]-\epsilon,\epsilon\right[$ to cover what is left. Everything will work. And the transition map will be the identity.

---

To prove that ${\bf x}^{-1}$ is continuous, it suffices to check that $\bf x$ is bijective, differentiable, and ${\rm d}{\bf x}_{(u,v)}$ has maximum rank for all $(u,v)$ in the domain. In other words, check that: $$\frac{\partial {\bf x}}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial {\bf x}}{\partial v}(u,v) \neq {\bf 0}.$$

Comment: How can I show that the inverse map is continuous?

Comment: I edited the answer, please check it.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect. If you have time would you take a look at my different question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330479/differential-forms-on-surfaces-show-that-n-cdot-nabla-times-v-eta-d-phi-o